# Create a single shortcut for multiple files

Tags: php, linux, filesystems, video-streaming, symlink

I am trying to merge multiple video files from my HLS online streaming service into a single downloadable file without duplicating them on my hard drive. Is there a way to generate a list of the drive sectors and create a shortcut that functions as a unified file? Currently, I buffer and send the files for download, but I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: The `readfile()` function will read from a URL and pass it through to the client, without saving the contents anywhere. You can call it in a loop to do multiple files.

Comment: This is not what I wanted, a 1-hour video file in HLS protocol is divided into about 1000 pieces and the user has to download 1000 files.
I collect these files in the buffer and send them to the user as a single file. This will fill the buffer and damage the RAM.
I am talking about 500TB of files and 1000 simultaneous downloads

Comment: @hjolfaei I think @Barmar is correct. All `readfile()` does is achieve the same thing as using the single M3U8 file (playlist) for your HLS content. So your video player is given a PHP link (not MP4 link) and the player receives chunked data (each file pieces) from the server (_ie:_ the script returns one long stream of data, connected by multiple calls, such that the player thinks it's receiving one long file)

Comment: When using the `readfile()` function, the file is indeed read into Apache's output buffer until the PHP script execution is completed. This means that the file content is stored in memory until the client finishes downloading the file.
When dealing with large files and a high number of downloads, storing the entire file content in memory for each  download can lead to excessive memory usage and potential performance issues. It is not an efficient approach.